# Convert XLSB files to csv in Linux on command line

Tags: linux, excel, command-line

I have thousands of XLSBs files (binary excel files). I'm on Ubuntu and need to convert them all to CSVs. Each files has lots of macros and tabs, however, all this content can be ignored as for each file I only need the data from the first tab.

Is there a way to do it via command line?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found it! If Libreoffice is installed we can do it via the command:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to csv file.xlsb
```

The `--headless` command prevents the GUI from opening

Comment: Saved a lot of time. Thank you very much

Comment: Any ideas on how to specify a tab?